# Как обнулить стиль point через атрибут класса?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```
function ShowPointer() {

  DeletePointer();
  var input = $('#searchInput').val().toLowerCase();
  console.log(input);
  let point = document.createElement('img');
  point.src='/znak_mestopolozhenia.png';
  var idObj ='pointer' + String(input);
  console.log(idObj);
  point.setAttribute('id', idObj);
  document.querySelector('#MainBox').appendChild(point);
  console.log(point);
}

function DeletePointer() {

  
  // point.classList.add('pointer');
  point.setAttribute('class', 'pointer');
  console.log(point);
  var dlt = document.querySelectorAll(".pointer");
  dlt.style = 'null';

  
  // document.point.style.display = 'none';
  // point.style = 'null';
}
```

Comment: вообщем, создал элемент с атрибутом id и хочу через class обнулить его стиль, но не получается присвоить этот атрибут, чтобы на него сослаться.
Ошибка в point.setAttribute('class', 'pointer');

Comment: Что такое `point` и откуда он по Вашему должен взяться внутри функции `DeletePointer()`?

Comment: point = <img> созданный в js, который потом интегрируется в html
Верное рассуждение, однако, на это не ругается прога, пробовал объявить point и в этой фции - безуспешно

Comment: С тем кодом что приведен здесь, `point` будет `undefined`. Да и что вообще значит, обнулить стиль через класс?

Comment: К тому же вот это `var dlt = document.querySelectorAll(".pointer");` вернет NodeList, а не один элемент.

Comment: я решил проблему, спасибо. даже метод querySelector (изначально хотел его использовать, а не querySelectorAll, не заметил просто) не понадобился.